# how to connect android studio to influxDB

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, influxdb

I plan to develop a "mobile version"  Will retrieve real-time data from influxDB continuously while the app is active to display my sensor data.

Answer (score 0):

you are going to want some kind of server infront of the InfluxDB instance. This server could be many things

here's two possibilities

1. a restful API implemented with your favorite language

- [InfluxDB NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/influxdb-nodejs) + [ExpressJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)

2. [graphql](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/using-graphql-with-influxdb-and-flux/)

I once used AWS and InfluxDB like this

1. python lambda function query data
2. api gateway infront of lambda
3. javascript calling the API gateway endpoint

there are ways to query the InfluxDB directly, however I've suggested adding a layer in between to handle business logic (i.e. authorization, manipulation, validation...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a RestAPI for you influxdb database service, you can then interact influxdb using https endpoints.

We have used in our project where used influx client liberary (.[NET](https://github.com/AdysTech/InfluxDB.Client.Net)), we have dedicated influx server infrastructure for best performance. You can choose your favorite language for the implementation.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/api_client_libraries/